# unstable connection with PPTPD on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, vpn

I have the following setup. My raspberry pi is behind a router and runs pptpd, 
I am connecting from another country from Ubuntu 12.04.

However the connection stays alive for very short period of time, as soon as I start browsing via the vpn, the connection drops.

Sometimes the connection drops immediately. 
This did not used to be the case and the only thing that I have changed is probably just updated my ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of pptpd.

You would need to gather logs to find out why the connection drops.  Look at http://poptop.sourceforge.net/ for some hints for how to do this.  You may get a faster response from the poptop-server@ mailing list.

The problem is very unlikely to have anything to do with the RPi, there's nothing unique about an RPi that should affect PPTP.  Another Debian or Ubuntu system in the same position should have the same problem.

Speculating: your country has a filter that blocks the connection, or your ISP does not properly handle it, or the router between your RPi and the internet does not properly support inbound PPTP port forwarding, or the path MTU discovery mechanism is broken at your ISP.  That last one can be worked around by reducing the MTU on the PPP interface.